# How to detect if a message is sent in Slack via the Slack Python API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to figure out how to do this and I've finally given up after attempting to checking the documentation, tutorials, and reverse-engineer some other people's bots.

Here is a small bit of code I tried to use to test it:

```
import slack
slack_token = 'xoxb-***-***-***'
rtmclient = slack.RTMClient(token=slack_token)

@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event="message")
def test(**payload):
    print("I'm finally working...")
    
rtmclient.start()
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: Its not clear where thing are not working. Do you get an error? Is your code executing but not returning anything?
Did you try with slackclient instead of slack?

Comment: @BastienHarkins I'm not getting any errors, but the code is not printing "I'm finally working..." when I send a DM or a message in a channel that the bot is also in. Also, slackclient is outdated? If I do "import slackclient" there is no such module.